# Fetch data in ComponentDidMount not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, fetch

I am trying to fetch data, set state and change route in componentDidMount, but it can not be done(only after clicking on the screen ). I guess there something has to do with asynchronous nature of fetch but how can it be fixed?

```
componentDidMount(){

AsyncStorage.multiGet([USER_TOKEN, USER_REFRESH_TOKEN,USER_REMEMBERED]).then((data) => {
  const userRemembered = JSON.parse(data[2][1])
  const userAccessToken = data[0][1]
  const userRefreshToken = data[1][1]

  if (userRemembered) {
    fetch("SOME_URL", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        refreshToken: userRefreshToken
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData); // only after clicking on the screen it is logged
      if (responseData.success) {
        AsyncStorage.multiSet([[USER_TOKEN,responseData.response.accessToken],[USER_REFRESH_TOKEN,responseData.response.refreshToken],[USER_REMEMBERED,JSON.stringify(true)]])
        this.setState({
          token:responseData.response.accessToken,
          refreshToken: responseData.response.refreshToken,
          isLoggedIn: true
        }) //only after clicking on the screen state is changed
        this.changeRoute(this.state) //only after clicking on the clicking on the screen route is changed
      }
      else {
        console.log("API is not responding");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
  else{
    console.log('user has not checked Remember Me');
  }
})
```

}

Comment: to reflect changes of state immediately once updated you should use in `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: is your control going to componentDidMount?if yes then fetch is not working right?

Comment: @JigarShah Maybe I am not understanding you correctly. Are you suggesting to change route in`componentDidUpdate ()`?

Comment: @VikramSaini Promise is working. nothing works after second `.then()`. If I click somewhere on the screen then it works, state is updated and route is changed, but not working when page loads, weird.

Comment: yes,all actions should be placed in `componentDidUpdate`, once you set the state it will reflect where you have placed.

Comment: fetch data in `componentDidMount` but use function to check state change and relevant actions in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: @JigarShah Yes but the route change in `componentDidUpdate` might not be a good idea as I have more then one `setState` on this page and wouldn't the route change be called on every state change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I had **Remote JS Debugging** turned on and it was messing things up. I turned it off and everything works fine.